# 「報告書」と「日報」の違いは何？

Tags: meaning

I have been working in Japanese office since 2 months. And my boss ask me for report(報告) of what I did that entire day in written format in Excel(日本だったらしょうがない). But he asked me to keep last day report as well and pile it up.

Now, On each Monday my boss asked me to create report of what I did last week.

So, My question is which one should I call 日報 and which one 報告書???

and If anyone have some links to explain what is what and its 書き方 is much appreciated.

Comment: I would suggest politely asking your boss this same question, or, failing that, asking a co-worker who would know what the practice in your office is (perhaps someone tasked with the same reporting).

Comment: Are you somehow forced to choose between 日報 and 報告書? There is also the word 週報, a “week report”, which might be useful to disambiguate things. If you [Google Images 週報](https://www.google.com/search?q=%E9%80%B1%E5%A0%B1&tbm=isch) you'll see some templates of week reports.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

- 報告書 is a formal "report (document)". A long report can consist of hundreds of pages (e.g., an aviation accident report).
- 日報, as its kanji suggest, is "**daily** report". It's a brief record of what you did or what happened on a day. It can be as short as a few lines. There is no common format for this. Unless your boss explicitly specified the format, a few lines of email might qualify as your 日報, but it depends on your workplace. You can use an image search to [see typical Excel日報](https://search.yahoo.co.jp/image/search?ei=UTF-8&fr=sfp_as&aq=-1&oq=&ts=1344&p=%E6%97%A5%E5%A0%B1).